# Trying to get property of non-object error in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying register in my app but this Error happened and I don't know why.
[image]

and my post.blade.php file has this code:

```
<div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title">

    <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">

        {{$post->title}}

    </a>

</h2>


<p class="blog-post-meta">

    {{$post->user->name }}
    {{$post->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}


</p>

{{$post->body}}
```

postcontroller has this code:

```
public function index()

   {
      $posts=Post::latest()->get();

     return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
   }
```

and index file is:

```
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        @include('posts.post')
    @endforeach

    <nav class="blog-pagination">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Older</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" href="#">Newer</a>
    </nav>

</div><!-- /.blog-main -->
```

Comment: did you pass `$post` from controller?

Comment: Check if you pass along the $post variable.

Comment: Are you sure created_at is actually send in $post?

Comment: @KirkBeard I did your suggest please check my question

Comment: Also add your controller lines here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code need to update like:

```
public function index()
{
   $posts=Post::with('users')->latest()->get();
   return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}

<p class="blog-post-meta">
   {{$post->users->name }}
   {{$post->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}
</p>
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: I checked your answer but this error happened : Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\Post].

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are including `post.blade.php` in `index.blade.php` file.

In above case you are not passing `$post` to `post.blade.php`. Your `foreach` loop will be like :

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @include('posts.post', ['post' => $post])
@endforeach
```

Comment: @HanieAsemi Can you `dd()` the `$post`.

Comment: where I add this method?

Comment: In your controller, before you returns the view.

Answer (score 0):

assume that you are including post.blade.php in index.blade.php file.

In above case you are not passing $post to post.blade.php. Your foreach loop will be like :

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   @include('posts.post', ['post' => $post])
@endforeach
```

Comment: I  guess that error is in user because other post object worked currently

Comment: did you try it the way i answerd ??